# AttributeError : int object has no attribute

Tags: python

```
class Point(object):
    ''' A point on a grid at location x, y '''

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X=x
        self.Y=y   

    def __str__(self):
        return "X=" + str(self.X), "Y=" + str(self.Y)


    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Point):
            raise TypeError("must be of type point")
        x= self.X+ other.X
        y= self.Y+ other.Y
        return Point(x, y)

p1= Point(5, 8)
print p1 + [10, 12]
```

When trying to add list or tuple at RHS i.e. print p1 + [10, 12], I'm getting

```
attributeError: int object has no attribute
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: I get `TypeError("must be of type point")`. Because you're adding a type other than a point, to the point. That's exactly what you told your code to do, what's the issue?

Comment: You are not adding points. `[10, 12]` clearly does not equal `Point(10,12)`. You are adding a) list to point, b) point to list. Both operations are not supported by your code right now. first one may potentially be implemented (but really shouldn't), second may not.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I can't reproduce the exact error you show, but I believe that is some sort of a "typo". You are trying to add a `list` instance to a `Point` instance, while the `__add__` method of the later throws the error whenever you try to add anything that is not a `Point` instance.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Point):
        raise TypeError("must be of type point")
```

You could possibly overcome it by adding a fair bit of polymorphism.

```
from collections import Sequence 


class Point(object):
    ...

    def _add(self, other):
        x = self.X + other.X
        y = self.Y + other.Y
        return Point(x, y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self._add(other)
        elif isinstance(other, Sequence) and len(other) == 2:
            return self._add(type(self)(*other))
        raise TypeError("must be of type point or a Sequence of length 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a comma instead of a plus. Look at

```
def __str__(self):
    return "X=" + str(self.X), "Y=" + str(self.Y)
```

Which should be

```
def __str__(self):
    return "X=" + str(self.X) + ", Y=" + str(self.Y)
```

At least on python3 when I correct it your code runs nicely. Obviously using `print(p1 + Point(10,12))`.